# arbitrary number of plots for grid.arrange

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, knitr, do.call

I'm trying to plot an arbitrary number of bar plots with rmarkdown separated by 2 columns. In my example there will be 20 total plots so I was hoping to get 10 plots in each column, however, I can't seem to get this to work with `grid.arrange`

```
plot.categoric = function(df, feature){
  df = data.frame(x=df[,feature])
  plot.feature = ggplot(df, aes(x=x, fill = x)) + 
    geom_bar() +
    geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(..count../1460)), stat='count', vjust=-.4) +
    labs(x=feature, fill=feature) +
    ggtitle(paste0(length(df$x))) +
    theme_minimal()
  return(plot.feature)
}


plist = list()
for (i in 1:20){
  plist = c(plist, list(plot.categoric(train, cat_features[i])))
}

args.list = c(plist, list(ncol=2))
do.call("grid.arrange", args.list)
```

When I knit this to html I'm getting the following output:

[image]

I was hoping I would get something along the lines of:

[image]

but even with this the figure sizes are still funky, I've tried playing with `heights` and `widths` but still no luck. Apologies if this is a long question

Comment: Check this out: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/

Comment: `grid.arrange(grobs=lapply(1:20, function(i) ggplot() ), ncol=2)` should work, but you need to resize the device to see the plots and legends clearly

Comment: `do.call(grid.arrange, c(ggcluster,list(ncol=2)))` This works for me, being ggcluster a list of ggplot objects. Number of ggplot elements in the list is different in any loop interation

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the `ggplot` objects in a list then you can easily build the two column graphic via `gridExtra::grid.arrange`.  Here is a simple example that will put eight graphics into a 4x2 matrix.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# Build a set of plots
plots <-
  lapply(unique(diamonds$clarity),
         function(cl) {
           ggplot(subset(diamonds, clarity %in% cl)) +
           aes(x = carat, y = price, color = color) +
           geom_point()
         })

length(plots)
# [1] 8

grid.arrange(grobs = plots, ncol = 2)
```

[image]